# Devices with 1280x800 screen size does not layout properly

Tags: android

I have the following simple layout which I used as a custom view for the action bar. The layout is displayed properly on all devices except devices with 1280x800 and 480x800 dimensions.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:background="@color/black">

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/accHistoryRadioGroup"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/journalRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/SettingsJournalTitle"
        android:textColor="@color/yellow" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@color/gray_lighter" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/closedPosRadioBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:button="@null"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/CommonClosedPosShort"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />
</RadioGroup>
```

On all devices: [image]
On a 1280x800 device (Genymotion Galaxy Note): [image]

I have tested with different Android versions. The version seems not to be the cause.

Edit: Any my question is: how can I remove the space between the "Closed Pos." textview and the divider ?

Edit 2: It seems that the space is already there even if the radiobutton contains no text
[image]

On the other hand, the radiobutton disappears on some of the other devices:
[image]

Edit 3: The more I look into this problem, the more I believe that setting button="@null" does not remove the background of the radio buttons when the radio buttons are used in the action bar and the device is 1280x800.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: not entirely sure about `android:gravity="center"` in the radiogroup

Comment: @GrahamSmith: I have just added my question :)

Comment: @njzk2: I have removed android:gravity="center" in the radiogroup. The result is the same.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html#menu_customviews why not use a standard AB and use a custom view for the right side. See the article link.

Comment: Because when I started working on the app, I wanted to move the activity title to the center of the action bar. Suddenly, when I wanted to change it back, it was already too late :) The amount of code I need to refactor is too high. 
I have just added a new edit. Please have a look.

Comment: You could try getting rid of the center vertical on he gravity attribute of the second radiobutton

Comment: Removing this does not help. I tried.